# Using a Selenium page object model in Perl, how do I pass a new page object back to the test script?

Tags: perl, selenium, pageobjects

I'm organizing my functional tests using a page object model.  One example of a test case is to log in and check for some text on the application's dashboard.  Toward that end I've got modules like `Loginpage.pm` and `Dashboard.pm` in my project, and a script like `log_in_and_check_text.pl`.

Now, the reason to use the page object model is obviously the Dashboard page is going to do a lot more than just display this text and it'll be used in different ways in lots of different test cases.  The [documentation on Page Object Models](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) suggests I'm going to want to create a `Loginpage` object to log in, then send back a `Dashboard` object upon success.

How do I do that in Perl?  Furthermore, is this necessary?  If I spin up my Selenium driver in the test script and not in those objects, can't I just create a new `Dashboard` instance in my test script using the same driver?

Comment: I personally don't like returning a different page...because what if you login, and it redirects you to different pages, based on what url you were trying to hit?  I would recommend instantiating all of your pages at the beginning (with the same driver), and then using/reusing them throughout your test.

Comment: @MrTi on the contrary, just return a common class between the two pages.

Comment: What do you mean by "a common class".  Do you mean a generic Page that could match any page?

Comment: Isn't the Selenium driver itself a common class?